# How can I make docker machine to get images from host before pulling any image for itself?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I found that every time I create a container in a new machine it is pulling image from docker hub. I have searched the web but found no well formed result. I have pulled the images from hub on host machine. now my question is how to make docker machine to check the host image location before pulling any image into virtualbox?  I want machines to share and save images from host's default location so that I can share images among multiple machines without pulling it from registry for each machine

Comment: What OS are you on? Images are stored in machines, not the host, so there is no host image location.

Comment: @warmoverflow Yes I know it. but I want machines to share and saves images from hosts default location so that I can share images among multiple machines without pulling it from registry for each machine. Updated  Question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a *new* machine, meaning a new VM, docker will indeed pull images from docker hub to the local VM docker image storage path:

```
/var/lib/docker/images
```

Each new machine has its own image cache.

If you want to share images amongst machine, you need one acting as your private registry, with its own certificate to enable https access.
See an [example here](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/nodes/kv/build#L27-L34), using [`gen_ssl_key_and_crt.sh`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/nodes/kv/gen_ssl_key_and_crt.sh) for the key/certificate generation:

```
./gen_ssl_key_and_crt.sh
if [[ "$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} registry 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]]; then
    docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
        -v $(pwd)/certs:/certs \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/crt \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/key \
        registry:2
fi
```

Then your other machine can pull from that registry, which is much faster, and which will pull from docker hub only once, the first time it sees it does not have in its own registry the image.

[For instance](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/46a600fa7d80a4021860128a4c06fcf5b6a2d138/nodes/blessed/build#L16-L18):

```
if [[ "$(docker images -q kv:5000/b2d/git:2.8.1 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]]; then
    docker pull kv:5000/b2d/git:2.8.1
fi
```

---

For a simpler workaround, see:

- "[How to change the default docker registry from docker.io to my private registry](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/registry_mirror/)"
- "[Run a local registry mirror](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/registry_mirror/)"

Comment: Thanks @VonC this definitely helps. But I am looking for simpler workaround. Can't I skip the registry setup and make machine able to check default image location on host before pulling images in machine while creating a container into it?

Comment: @nmrony see http://stackoverflow.com/q/33054369/6309: I would setup a registry mirror: https://docs.docker.com/registry/mirror/

Comment: @ScottStensland Thank you. I have included the link in the answer for more visibility.