# Getting docker pull to default pull from a private registry?

Tags: security, docker, registry, containers

So when you docker pull an image, it by default looks to the Docker Hub registry to find the image. Is there any way that I can make it so when I docker pull, it by default looks into my private registry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default docker registry from docker.io to my private registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry and I believe that it is still the case that you can not change the default. (Something like npmrc would be nice tho.)

Comment: Alright yeah, I saw that post but was wondering if that had changed. Thanks anyways.