# Using Docker Client with Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry, acr

I want to use local docker client with the Azure Container Registry.
I got the access keys for ACR.  I use them as below:

```
docker login <acrname>.azurecr.io
username: <type>
password:<copy/paste>
```

docker successfully logs me in.

```
docker image list
```

The above lists local images. So, how do I get docker client to select the ACR as registry by default?

If [I can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry), why doesn't the below work?

```
docker --host exampleacr.azurecr.io image list
```

Getting an error:

> error during connect: Get
>   http://exampleacr.azurecr.io:2375/v1.40/images/json: dial tcp
>   40.71.10.222:2375: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding so far:  The --host parameter is for the remote docker daemon.  ACR is JUST a registry.  Do not expect a docker daemon.

If you know the image use

```
docker pull exampleacr.azurecr.io/image
```

AND use local machine with the docker daemon to create containers and generally work with the image.  I can list the repositories and tags using

```
az acr repository list --name exampleacr
```

Lists "cloudlene/example" as a repository

```
az acr repository show-tags -n exampleacr --repository cloudlene/example
```

Lists "2057,2058,2059 as tags
and then PULL with docker client:

```
docker pull exampleacr.azurecr.io/cloudlene/example:2059
```