# Redirect docker pull

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-pull

Does exist the opportunity to redirect `pull` (or `push`), when `docker` tries to get/send image from  `dockerHub`,without changing `docker pull` arguments?
For example:

```
docker pull gcr.io/distroless/static@sha256:23aa732bba4c8618c0d97c26a72a32997363d591807b0d4c31b0bbc8a774bddf
```

redirect from `gcr.io/distroless/static` to `my.repo.com/gcr.io/distroless/static`, without changing `docker pull` arguments.

I want to use redirection for example without changing `Dockerfile`

Comment: does this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry ?

Comment: @yAzou - `...not currently possible to change the default registry` => looks bad.

Comment: @yAzou -  but many exists a way resolve it outside the docker?

Comment: The registry definition is a part of the docker cli...the only way to define it "outisde" is by creating a environment variable and call it....but i do not see any reason to do that

Comment: @yAzou -  Which `variable` I have to override/create? How use this approach?

Comment: if you are using linux you can configure the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file. Have a look on this article : https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/setup-private-docker-registry/