# any chance to redirect the docker image name to private registry server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I knew I can tag the image name from official name with private image name and push to it

```
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine <abc.jrog.io>/alpine
docker push <abc.jrog.io>/alpine
```

But this is not the case when I deal with Kubernetes helm charts, especailly with sub-charts.

I can set new image name in `values.yaml`, but if one chart calls other charts, I can't make this works.

So currently I have to pull all charts and rename images and add private registry server as prefix.

Are there any ways I can do that transparently?

For example, if I pull image `alpine`, the computer/server can automatically to get the image from private registry without any image name changed?

So the ideal is very close to git insteadOf feature.

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

with above configuraiton, I can force `https://` to `git://` always

I'd like to set the similar in `docker pull`, it is not pull from hub.docker.io, but from `<abc.jrog.io>`

Answer (score 2):

What you want, is to configure a custom *default registry*. Wether this is possible or how to do it depends on what container runtime and nodes that you are using. See e.g. [How to change the default docker registry from docker.io to my private registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry)