# How to change default K8s cluster registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How to change our k8s cluster from docker.io to our private registry so we don't have to mention the docker registry host on every image?

Comment: image pull secrets can be created and then the path to container registry can be given

Comment: [How to change the default docker registry from docker.io to my private registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry) discusses this in the pure-Docker case; unless you have a mirror of Docker Hub it's not usually considered a good idea.  Making it a configurable parameter in a Helm chart could be one reasonable approach.

Comment: @DavidMaze, could you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

you could set your [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) to modify *image.spec.containers.image* values

I wouldn't recommend doing this though.

Answer (score -6):

*This is a Community Wiki answer partially based on other user's comments, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As you can read in [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) of the official kubernetes documentation, it can be configured on a container runtime level ( in this case `Docker` ) by [creating a `Secret` based on existing Docker credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials) and later you can [refer to such alternative cofiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret) in your `Pod` specification as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets: 
  - name: regcred
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question of how to change the default registry that the cluster uses.