# Can we change kubernetes image registry search list?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, container-registry, docker-registry-mirror

For example, I have an internal docker registry for my kube cluster, hosted on `internal-docker-registry.io:5000`.

When the pod from the kube cluster pulling image `busybox`, I don't want to pull from docker hub `docker.io`. But instead I want it to pull from `internal-docker-registry.io:5000`.

*Note that I cannot change the image name to `internal-docker-registry.io:5000/busybox` since I don't own the spec and there are too man these kind of third party image in my cluster.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry

Comment: See also [How to change default K8s cluster registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026479/how-to-change-default-k8s-cluster-registry) which asks the same question.  As the question @DanielFarrell mentions indicates, there is no "image registry search list"; an image name without a registry _always_ uses `docker.io`, to avoid surprises where _e.g._ `FROM ubuntu` means something different depending on local configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted community wiki answer to summarize the topic:

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) well mentioned in the comment:

> **there is no "image registry search list"**; an image name without a registry *always* uses `docker.io`, to avoid surprises where *e.g.*  `FROM ubuntu` means something different depending on local configuration.

So if you can't change the image name to internal-docker-registry.io:5000/busybox then unfortunately you don't have the option to get the image from your private registry (according to David's comment).

See also similar questions:

[How to change the default docker registry from docker.io to my private registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry)

[How to change default K8s cluster registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026479/how-to-change-default-k8s-cluster-registry)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete guide on how to accomplish this in the official kubernetes documentation [1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/