# Docker: get list of all the registries configured on a host

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Can docker be connected to more than one registry at a time and how to figure out which registries it is currently connected too?

```
$ docker help | fgrep registr
login       Log in to a Docker registry
logout      Log out from a Docker registry
pull        Pull an image or a repository from a registry
push        Push an image or a repository to a registry
```

As you can see, there is no option to list the registries.  I did find
a way by running:

```
$ docker system info | fgrep -i registr
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

So...  one regsitry at a time only?  It is not like `apt` where one can point to more than one source?  Anybody can point me to some good documentation about docker and registries?

Oddly, I search the web to no vail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aside from `docker login`, Docker isn't "connected to a registry" *per se*.  Registry names are part of the image name, and Docker will connect to a registry server if it needs to pull an image.

As a specific example, the [official Docker image for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docker.html) is on a non-default registry run by Elastic.  The example in that documentation is

```sh
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           registry host name
```

You don't need to otherwise configure your system to connect to that registry, download an index, or anything else.  In fact, you don't even need this `docker pull` command; if you directly `docker run` the image, Docker will download it if it doesn't have a copy locally.

The default registry is Docker Hub, `docker.io`, and [this cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054369/how-to-change-the-default-docker-registry-from-docker-io-to-my-private-registry).

There are several alternate registries out there.  The various public-cloud providers each have their own, and there are also several free-standing image registries.  Each has its own instructions on how to set it up.  You always need to include the registry name as part of the image name.  The [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) has a simple name syntax, for example, so if you use GCR then you can

```sh
# build an image locally, labeled to be stored in GCR
# (this step does not contact or use GCR at all)
docker build gcr.io/my-name/my-image:tag

# authenticate to the registry
# (normally GCR has a Google-specific login sequence)
docker login https://gcr.io

# push the image
docker push gcr.io/my-name/my-image:tag

# run the image, pulling it if not present
docker run ... gcr.io/my-name/my-image:tag
```